# ReadTheDocs badge red on Github, but should be green

Tags: github, markdown, read-the-docs

*Edit* The badge appears green on GitHub now as well. Could it be related to caching done by GitHub?

---

*Edit 2* Oh, it's red again.

---

The badge in the ReadTheDocs project [here](https://readthedocs.org/projects/nrc4d/) is green.

> [image: green on ReadTheDocs]

But when I paste the badge HTML or Markdown code into my [GitHub repositorie's README.md](https://github.com/nr-python/nr.c4d) file, it always appears red.

> [image: red on GitHub]

- I've checked about 20 times now that the badge code is correct. It appears green everywhere else (eg. when I paste the badge code in http://www.ctrlshift.net/project/markdowneditor/).
- I have also opened the GitHub page with another internet browser and from my mobile phone, but it's still red so it's not a client-side caching problem.
- When I go to the badge image source directly, I also get a green badge.

What the heck is wrong?

---

**README.md**

```
<h1>
  <span>nr.c4d - Cinema 4D Python Toolbox</span>
  <a href='http://nrc4d.readthedocs.org/en/latest/?badge=latest'>
    <img src='https://readthedocs.org/projects/nrc4d/badge/?version=latest' alt='Documentation Status' />
  </a>
</h1>

This module is the successor of `c4dtools` and is currently being
developed to version 2.0.0. You can find the older versions of the
`c4dtools` package in the other branches.
```

Answer (score 0):

That is due to the cache of your browser. If you clean the cache, access with another browser, or use Incognito mode, then it will turn green.

Comment: Quote: > I have also opened the GitHub page with another internet browser and from my mobile phone, but it's still red so it's not a client-side caching problem.

Comment: Anyway, the issue doesn't seem to be reproducible anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Github uses image cache, so if it captured the image when the build was failing it will remain like that on the page for some time.